# How to find the key of a minimum value in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code that generates a nested dictionary.

```
import random
import numpy as np

dict1 = {}
for i in range(0,2):
    dict2 = {}
    for j in range(0,3):
        dict2[j] = random.randint(1,10)
    dict1[i] = dict2
```

For example it can generate the following content of `dict1`:

```
{0: {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 5}, 1: {0: 3, 1: 10, 2: 10}}
```

I want to find the sub-key of a minimum value for the fixed key. For example, for the fixed key `0`, the minimum value among the nested dictionary values is `2` which refers to thew sub-key `1`. Therefore the result should be `1`:

```
result=find_min(dict1[0])
result
1
```

How can I develop such `find_min` function?

Comment: And which part of the task seems to be the problem? You should 1) take the dictionary associated with the _first key_, then 2) read its keys (let's call them subkeys) and lastly 3) find which of the subkeys is the minimum.

Comment: And, how is this related to `numpy` at all?

Comment: Finding the minimum value of an iterable collection (e.g. the smallest member of a list) is covered quite well in many other postings and tutorials.  Where are you stuck in developing your algorithm?

Comment: @zvone: I know how to read keys and values: `dict1[0].keys()` and `dict1[0].values()`. But I don't know how to find the key of the minimum value.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Well, `min(dict1[0].keys())`, or just `min(dict1[0])`, which is the same.

Comment: @zvone: well, I am thinking to use `min` of `numpy`: imports bumpy as np. np.min(...)`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @zvone: It will find the minimum key, not the key of the minimum value.

Comment: Guys, before down voting, please read the question more carefully and do not propose wrong solutions.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Use `numpy` functions to operate on `numpy` objects (if there is a good reason to have `numpy` objects at all). Use Python functions to operate on Python objects (like integers, lists, dictionaries).

Comment: `min(mydict[0].items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`?

Comment: @ScalaBoy I would say you are getting downvoted mostly because you just asked for "how to do this?", rather than showing what you did and asking why some part of it does not work. Also, it would be easier to understand the question if it was further simplified. You already know ho to fetch the sub-dict, so the question would be much simpler if you asked e.g. "how to find the key in dict corresponding to the minimum value"

Comment: @zvone: Isn't is the same as asking "how to find the key of a minimum value in a nested dictionary?"

Comment: `{k:min(d, key=d.get) for k, d in dict1.items()}`

Comment: @ScalaBoy Well, your question is then actually two questions: "how to find the nested dictionary?" and "how to find the key of a minimum value in a dictionary?", so both questions ask for an answer, which is more work than answering just one question, and more work understanding what was asked...

Comment: @zvone: thanks for your recommendations. I will consider them. But anyway I find this down-voting criteria a bit subjective.

Comment: @ScalaBoy Of course voting is subjective, it always is ;) Anyway, I'm just saying how things are. I suggest also reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reverse the keys and the values, then obtain the key with the minimum value:

```
 a = {0: {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 5}, 1: {0: 3, 1: 10, 2: 10}}
 dict(zip(a[0].values(),a[0].keys())).get(min(a[0].values()))
```

here we create a new dictionary whose keys and values are the reverse of the original dictionary. eg

```
dict(zip(a[0].values(),a[0].keys()))
Out[1575]: {7: 0, 2: 1, 5: 2}
```

Then from here, we obtain the minimum value in the original dictionary and use that as the key in this reversed dictionary

## EDIT

As indicated in the comments, one can simply use the `key` within  the `min` function:

```
   min(a[0],key = a[0].get)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your approach. What `zip` does here?

Comment: @ScalaBoy `zip` is a function that combines two arrays together elementwise. try `list(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))` and see what happens

Comment: May be easier to understand if a[0] was pulled out. The question would probably have been clearer as "How to find the key of a minimum value in a dictionary."

Comment: To get the key that contains the smallest value for dictionary `d` do `min(d, key=d.get)`.  No need to get more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the sub-dict for key `0`, just do:

```
sub_dict = dict1[0]
```

Then, to find the key corresponding to the minimum value:

```
min_value, min_key = min((value, key) for key, value in sub_dict.items())
```

Comment: `min_key = min(sub_dict, key=sub_dict.get)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, that is even better.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

def find_min(d, fixed_key):
    # Given a dictionary of dictionaries d, and a fixed_key, get the dictionary associated with the key
    myDict = d[fixed_key]
    # treat the dictionary keys as a list
    # get the index of the minimum value, then use it to get the key
    sub_key = list(myDict.keys())[myDict.values().index(min(myDict.values()))]
    return sub_key

dict1 = {0: {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 5}, 1: {0: 3, 1: 10, 2: 10}}

print dict1
print find_min(dict1, 0)
```

Comment: This works, but is more complex than needed: it makes a copy of all keys, then finds minimum of all values, then goes through the values once again to find the index of the minimum. In the end, it has to go through the whole dictionary 3 times. That is usually not a problem, but is not needed here...